# Symfony2 before and after filters doesn't work with containeraware

Tags: php, symfony

I have multilingual site that uses xml for diffrent languages. (I know that Symfony Translations exists, but i'm implementing my own system for accessing and taking xml elements values and i wanted to test it).

I'm not going to put the entire code here for readability, the implementation is same as [in this link.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)

I have a service under a name `xml_handler`. The service I fetched in the controller with `$this->get('xml_handler')`. But then, I started using Symfony2 best practices and started extending ContainerAware. After that, the code below, which is defined as a Before Listener, failed.

```
if($controller[0] instanceof LanguageInterface) {
        $xmlHandler = $controller[0]->get('xml_handler');
```

It raises an error that there is no `get()` method in `$controller` (IndexController is the name of the controller that extends ContainerAware, but that doesn't really matter, just for clarity)

The problem arose after I stopped extending Controller but started to extend ContainerAware, as i said earlier.

So, how do i get the `get()` method, which is protected so obviously, trying :

```
$controller[0]->container->get('xml_handler')
```

Doesn't work. I've looked at the API but there isn't a `getContainer()` method.

I guess, the questing is, how do I access ContainerAware outside the controller, in my case, in the Before filter?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass all the required dependencies to your listener constructor:

In your listener :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\EventListener;

class MyListener
{
    private $xmlHandler;

    public function __construct($xmlHandler)
    {
        $this->xmlHandler = $xmlHandler;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($controller[0] instanceof LanguageInterface) {
            $this->xmlHandler->doSomething(...);

            // ...
```

In your configuration file you have to ask the dependency injection component to provide the xml_handler service as an argument of your listener constructor (a dependency).

```
services:
    acme_my.listener.action:
        class: Acme\MyBundle\EventListener\MyListener

        arguments:
            - "@xml_handler"

        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method:  onKernelController }
```